# add variable in rewrite url

Tags: php

I got a rewritten url that looks like this:

http://www.mysite.com/users/login/

it's rewritten from http://www.mysite.com?module=users&class=login

The thing is: for the login, I want the return url.

I thought i could just do this:

http://www.mysite.com/users/login/?returnurl=http://www.mysite.com/whatever/url/we/are/at

but when I var_dump $_GET all I get is module and class.

How can I have the returnurl as well?

Comment: Please show your mod_rewrite statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the   [`[QSA]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html) to your rewrite rule. Example:

```
 RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```